# Codigniter перенаправление на https

Tags: https, codigniter

Скажите пожалуйста перенаправлять на *Https* протокол,и должен ли для этого обязательно быть установлеть *SSL*?

Comment: Да, SSL обязателен.

Answer (score 1):

попробуйте так:

```
$config['base_url'] = "http".((isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] == "on") ? "s" : "")."://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].str_replace(basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']),"",$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']);
```

вместо:

```
$config['base_url'] = "http://www.example.com"
```

Это перенаправить вас всегда в указанных http или https. можно не указывать домен!

---

Дополнение к предыдушему, Можно сделать helper как:

```
<?php  if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

function is_https_on()
{
    return isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] == 'on';
}

function use_ssl($turn_on = TRUE)
{
    $url = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

    if ( $turn_on )
    {
        if ( ! is_https_on() && $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] != 'localhost')
        {
            redirect('https://' . $url, 'location', 301 );
            exit;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if ( is_https_on() )
        {
            redirect('http://' . $url, 'location', 301 );
            exit;
        }
    }
}

/* End of file https_helper.php */
/* Location: ./application/helpers/https_helper.php */
```

Тут можно даже указывать для отдельный страниц значение HTTPS/HTTP.

Можно использовать просто:

```
use_ssl();
```

в начале скрипта для использовании HTTPS.

Если нужно HTTP, просто:

```
use_ssl(FALSE);
```

[ссылка тут](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8657625/4953620)

---

Вариант №2

с помощью .htaccess

```
RewriteRule ^.*$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Спасибо буду пробовать

Comment: Не работает ваш вариант!

Comment: @quaresma89 какую ошибку дает? если вручную написать через https работает сам сайт?

Comment: SSL connection error ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR

Comment: @quaresma89 у вас не настроен https на сервере. Попробуйте настройки изменить